# Python error - writing data from multiple files into one - Index error

Tags: python

I am trying to read multiple files and extract specific column based on comparing their ranges and trying to append them in a single column in a new file (separated by commas).

Say, all 5th and 8th column from 10 files and appending them in a single file separated by commas. (4th column of all files separated by commas and 7th column of all files separated by commas and the 4th and 7th column separated by tabs).

I get an Index error saying the index is out of range for the below line,

```
x2 = field_split[3] + "," + x
x3 = field_split[4] + "," + x1
```

I do not understand the error here. Can anyone kindly explain it to me (I know what an index error is but why in this case I am receiving one).

I have attached the code here.

```
import bz2
import sys
import linecache


in_F=open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
Temp=inputFile.read().splitlines()
Out_F=open("outFile.tsv", "w+")

i=0
n=0
for files in Temp:
    if files.endswith("bz2"):
        file=bz2.BZ2File(files, 'r')
    else:
        file=open(files, 'r')

    l=0
    i=i+1
    for line in file:
        field=line.split()
        if len(field) > 9:
            l=l+1
            if (field[1] == str(n) and field[2]  == str(n+5000)):
                x = field[4]
                x1 = field[7]
                n=n+5000

            else:
                x = field[4]
                x1 = field[7]
                n = field[1] + str(5000)

            if (i == 1):
                Out_F.write(field[0]+"\t"+field[1]+"\t"+field[2]+"\t"+x+"\t"+x1+"\n")

            else:
                lines=linecache.getline("outFile.tsv", l).rstrip('\n')
                field_split = lines.split()
                x2 = field_split[3] + "," + x
                x3 = field_split[4] + "," + x1
                Out_F.write(field_split[0]+"\t"+field_split[1]+"\t"+field_split[2]+"\t"+x2+"\t"+x3+"\n")

    Out_F.seek(0,0)

in_F.close()
Out_F.close()
```

Comment: You are assuming that `lines` has at least 5 items separated by space; if it has less than those (or its a blank line) then you'll get the exception.

Comment: Can you just give a rough idea of how your output should be

Comment: A common issue is when there is a blank line in the file.

Comment: I have added a sample of the output format. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your code produces the desired output? For me it looks like it appends rows to outfile with the same field_split[0], [1] and [2] as the line previousely read from the same file, thus creating multiple entries with the same begin and end...

Answer (score 0):

I think your `lines=linecache.getline("outFile.tsv", l).rstrip('\n')` line is trying to read in the `outFile.tsv` before python has flushed any contents to the file.  Try adding a `Out_F.flush()` after your `Out_F.write()`.

Comment: Thank you Joe for the suggestion. I tried flush() method, but it did not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

### Linecache caches your file

From the linechace dcumentation for **linecache.getline**:

> This function will never raise an exception — it will return '' on errors

I think you try to read a line `l` that is not part of the file.

From the **linecache** documentation:

> The linecache module allows one to get any line from any file, while attempting to optimize internally, using a cache

Probably linecache creates a cache of your file and thus does not read the current version of your file in which you have written your line.

You can use **checkcache** before getline to make sure your cache is up to date. **clearcache** can be used to force reading the newest version of your file.

*I think (altoough I am not sure about the exact implementation of linecache) using linecache is unnecessary here, as the main benefit of linecache over native fileIO seems to be caching of the file. Obviousely, if you change your file, caching has no benefit.*

My suggestion: Read everything into a dictionary or list and only create the output file once all input is read (assuming your input files are not very large)